# Barryvdh/laravel-dom-pdf Issues with html entities and random CSS

Tags: laravel-4, pdf-generation

I am using this excellent package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

To download a view to a customers computer.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('doc_generation.mot', ['car' => $car]);
return $pdf->download($vrm .' MS.pdf');
```

Everything works fine, but no html entities are being shown on the pdf. Have tried the tick itself, and ✔ but both don't show.

I also have a div:

```
.number-plate {
    background: #FFD307;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Where the padding isn't shown on the output PDF. Although padding used elsewhere on other selectors is fine.

Anyone know how to fix these issues?

Comment: For me, HTML entities are showing up as a ?